# how to setup one to one relationships between tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a user table and a user profile table.A user can have exactly one profile and a profile belongs to exactly one user.Also there are three kinds of users buyers, sellers and broker having respective tables.How to create tables in Mysql for this design ? I am confused over the syntax to use for the tables in mysql

Answer (score 0):

One-to-one relationships occur when there is exactly one record in the first table that corresponds to exactly one record in the related table.

MySQL does not contains any “ready” options to define the one-to-one relationship, but, if you want to enforce it, you can add a foreign key from one primary key to the other primary key, by doing this, both tables will have the one-to-one relationship automatically.

Example

Here’s an example to define a one-to-one relationship in MySQL.

USER TABLE
user_id(PK),
name

USER PROFILE TABLE
user_id(FK),
age,
desc,
city